# SDL2 - function supposed to return True evaluates to False

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2, following LazyFoo's tutorial. I've reached the loading TTF Fonts part and I've seemingly followed everything he did, except adding two extra TTF_Font and SDL_Renderer parameters

```
bool LTexture::loadFromRenderedText(TTF_Font *&gFont, std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor, SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer)
{
    //Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    //Render text surface
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor );
    if( textSurface == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create texture from surface pixels
        mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, textSurface );
        if( mTexture == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Unable to create texture from rendered text! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get image dimensions
            mWidth = textSurface->w;
            mHeight = textSurface->h;
        }

        //Get rid of old surface
        SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is the function, and this is where it's called:

```
    gFont = TTF_OpenFont( "Font/comicSans.ttf", 28 );
    if( gFont == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load COMIC_SANS font! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Render text
        SDL_Color textColor = { 0, 0, 0 };
        if( !gTextTexture.loadFromRenderedText(gFont, "Hello I am hot", textColor, gRenderer));
        {
            printf( "Failed to render text texture!\n" );
            success = false;
        }
    }
```

if `succes` is false, the program prints "Failed loading media"

This is the output I get from running the program, notice how there are no actual SDL or TTF errors, only the one that appears when `loadFromRendereredText` returns false, which it doesn't, as I have set it to return 1:

```
Failed to render text texture!
Failed to load media!
```

The only actual difference from my files and LazyFoo's files are that my LTexture class is in a separate file than main, and that's why for some reason I couldn't use `gFont` and `gRenderer` (global variables)
Any idea what might be causing this?

FULL CODE:

main.cpp:

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2019)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "LTexture.h"

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
void close();


//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

TTF_Font *gFont = NULL;

LTexture gTextTexture;

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Load media
        if( !loadMedia() )
        {
            printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            //Main loop flag
            bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event event;

            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) != 0 )
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }

                //Clear screen
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

                gTextTexture.render(gRenderer, (SCREEN_WIDTH - gTextTexture.getWidth()) / 2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT - gTextTexture.getHeight()) / 2);
                //Update screen
                SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
            }
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}


bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create renderer for window
            gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            if( gRenderer == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initialize renderer color
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );

                //Initialize PNG loading
                int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ) )
                {
                    printf( "SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError() );
                    success = false;
                }
                //Initialize SDL_ttf
                if( TTF_Init() == -1 )
                {
                    printf( "SDL_ttf could not initialize! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Open the font
    gFont = TTF_OpenFont( "Font/comicSans.ttf", 28 );
    if( gFont == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load COMIC_SANS font! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Render text
        SDL_Color textColor = { 0, 0, 0 };
        if( !gTextTexture.loadFromRenderedText(gFont, "Hello I am hot", textColor, gRenderer));
        {
            printf( "Failed to render text texture!\n" );
            success = false;
        }
    }


    return success;
}

void close()
{

    //Free loaded images
    gTextTexture.free();

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( gRenderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    TTF_CloseFont(gFont);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;
    gFont = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    TTF_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

LTexture.h:

```
#ifndef LTEXTURE_INCLUDED
#define LTEXTURE_INCLUDED


#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

//Texture wrapper class
class LTexture
{
    public:
        //Initializes variables
        LTexture();

        //Deallocates memory
        ~LTexture();

        //Loads image at specified path
        bool loadFromFile( std::string path, SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer);

        //Loads image from string text
        bool loadFromRenderedText(TTF_Font *&gFont, std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor, SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer);

        //Deallocates texture
        void free();

        //Set color modulation
        void setColor( Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue );

        //Set blending
        void setBlendMode( SDL_BlendMode blending );

        //Set alpha modulation
        void setAlpha( Uint8 alpha );

        //Renders texture at given point
        void render(SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip = NULL, double angle = 0.0, SDL_Point* center = NULL, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE );

        //Gets image dimensions
        int getWidth(){return mWidth;}
        int getHeight(){return mHeight;}

    private:
        //The actual hardware texture
        SDL_Texture* mTexture;

        //Image dimensions
        int mWidth;
        int mHeight;
};
#endif // LTEXTURE_INCLUDED
```

LTexture.cpp:

```
#include "LTexture.h"

LTexture::LTexture()
{
    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;
}

LTexture::~LTexture()
{
    //Deallocate resources
    free();
}


bool LTexture::loadFromFile(std::string path, SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer)
{
    free();

    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    SDL_Surface *loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    if(loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), IMG_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        //Color key image
        SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
        if(newTexture == NULL)
        {
            printf( "Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            mWidth = loadedSurface->w;
            mHeight = loadedSurface->h;
        }
        SDL_FreeSurface( loadedSurface );
    }

    mTexture = newTexture;
    return mTexture != NULL;
}

bool LTexture::loadFromRenderedText(TTF_Font *&gFont, std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor, SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer)
{
    //Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    //Render text surface
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor );
    if( textSurface == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create texture from surface pixels
        mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, textSurface );
        if( mTexture == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Unable to create texture from rendered text! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get image dimensions
            mWidth = textSurface->w;
            mHeight = textSurface->h;
        }

        //Get rid of old surface
        SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
    }

    return 1;
}

void LTexture::free()
{
    if(mTexture != NULL){
        SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
        mTexture = NULL;
        mWidth = 0;
        mHeight = 0;
    }
}

void LTexture::setColor( Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue )
{
    //Modulate texture
    SDL_SetTextureColorMod( mTexture, red, green, blue );
}

void LTexture::setBlendMode( SDL_BlendMode blending )
{
    //Set blending function
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode( mTexture, blending );
}

void LTexture::setAlpha( Uint8 alpha )
{
    //Modulate texture alpha
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod( mTexture, alpha );
}

void LTexture::render(SDL_Renderer *&gRenderer, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip, double angle, SDL_Point *center, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    //Set rendering space and render to screen
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };

    if( clip != NULL )
    {
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
    }


    SDL_RenderCopyEx( gRenderer, mTexture, clip, &renderQuad, angle, center, flip );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of your if statement.

```
if( !gTextTexture.loadFromRenderedText(gFont, "Hello I am hot", textColor, gRenderer));
    {
        printf( "Failed to render text texture!\n" );
        success = false;
    }
```

That semicolon will create an empty statement for that if block, it will cause your

```
{
        printf( "Failed to render text texture!\n" );
        success = false;
}
```

to always execute.  It's like this,

```
if(.....)
   ;

{
   ....
}
```

Comment: If it returns true, that outputs "Failed to render text texture". That is what it does, it doesn't return false.

Comment: OOOOH GOD, I didn't see that! thank you so much! I knew something was wrong with that if statement, god damn it, thank you so much!